# Python subprocess echo a unicode literal

Tags: python, unicode, subprocess, unicode-literals

I'm aware that questions like this have been asked before. But I'm not finding a solution.

I want to use a unicode literal, defined in my python file, with the subprocess module. But I'm not getting the results that I need. For example the following code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
import codecs
import subprocess
cmd = ['echo', u'你好']
new_cmd = []
for c in cmd:
    if isinstance(c,unicode):
        c = c.encode('utf-8')
    new_cmd.append(c)
subprocess.call(new_cmd)
```

prints out

```
ä½ å¥½
```

If I change the code to

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
import codecs
import subprocess
cmd = ['echo', u'你好']
new_cmd = []
for c in cmd:
    if isinstance(c,unicode):
        c = c.encode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())
    new_cmd.append(c)
subprocess.call(new_cmd)
```

I get the following

```
??
```

At this stage I can only assume I'm, repeatedly, making a simple mistake. But I'm having a hard time figuring out what it is. How can I get echo to print out the following when invoked via python's subprocess

```
你好
```

Edit:

The version of Python is 2.7. I'm running on Windows 8 but I'd like the solution to be platform independent.

Comment: Check you locale system. Try to setlocale https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html

Comment: Oh, I thought you would actually have that problem too. @no_test proposed direction is probably a better idea then.

Comment: @no_test - Do you have an example. I've read the page but I'm not understanding it. I'd guess this is about setting my computers language page. But why is that necessary if I can copy & paste the echo onto the command line. Should it not already be able to handle these characters?

Comment: `import locale
# Store your system locale
loc=locale.getlocale()
# change locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, ('zh_CN','UTF8'))
# return to system locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, loc)`

Comment: @ShaneGannon, out of interest if you pass a string instead and use shell=True what do you see?

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham - If I do "subprocess.call('echo 你好', shell=True)" I get "ä½ å¥½"

Comment: It sounds like `subprocess` itself is encoding the string to the wrong character set. If you do `chcp` at the command line what does it return? Edit: no it's not `subprocess`, I missed the part where you `encode` the parameters.

Comment: @Mark Ransom - My default cmd returns 850 when I run chcp

Comment: That's weird, that code page isn't capable of displaying the characters you want. How is the `echo` working when you type it?

Comment: Honestly don't know. Windows confuses me in this regard. I get that Linux/Unix use utf-8 by default & as a result should be able to support all characters. I'm not sure how Windows gets away with it. It not only supports echo but mkdir as well.

Comment: You say in another comment that you use `Conemu`. That's probably why it works when you type it by hand, because `echo` is a shell built-in command. When you use `subprocess` with `shell=True`, it uses the default `cmd.exe`.

Comment: Ah.... no. You're right. First time I came across a difference between ConEmu and cmd. It does not work when run from a normal cmd. i.e. "你好" gets converted into "??". That was super confusing. Good insight.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77006/discussion-on-question-by-shane-gannon-python-subprocess-echo-a-unicode-literal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Conclusion:** Pay attention to character encodings (there are three different character encodings here). Use Python 3 if you want portable Unicode support (pass arguments as Unicode, don't encode them) or make sure that the data can be represented using current character encodings from the environment (encode using `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` on Python 2 as you do in the 2nd code example).

---

The first code example is incorrect. The effect is the same as (run it in IDLE -- `py -3 -midlelib`):

```
>>> print(u'你好'.encode('utf-8').decode('mbcs')) #XXX DON'T DO IT!
ä½ å¥½
```

where `mbcs` codec uses your [Windows ANSI code page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/05/31/144893.aspx) (typically: `cp1252` character encoding -- it may be different e.g., `cp1251` on Russian Windows).

Python 2 uses `CreateProcess` macros to start a subprocess that is equivalent to `CreateProcessA` function there. `CreateProcessA`  interprets input bytes as being encoded using your Windows ANSI encoding. It is *unrelated* to the Python source code encoding (utf-8 in your case).

It is expected that you get mojibake if you use a wrong encoding.

---

Your second code example should work if input characters can be represented using Windows code page such as `cp1252` (to enable encoding from Unicode to bytes) and if `echo` uses Unicode API to print to Windows console such as [`WriteConsoleW()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19206014/4279) (see Python 3 package [`win-unicode-console`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/win_unicode_console) -- it enables `print(u'你好')` *whatever* your chcp ("OEM") is as long as the font in console supports the characters) *or* the characters can be represented using OEM code page (used by `cmd.exe`) such as `cp437` (run `chcp` to find out yours). `??` question marks indicate that `你好` can't be represented using your console encoding.

To support arbitrary Unicode arguments (including characters that can't be represented using either Windows ("ANSI") or MS-DOS (OEM) code pages), you need `CreateProcessW` function (that is used by Python 3). See [Unicode filenames on Windows with Python & subprocess.Popen()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1910275/4279).

Comment: Unfortunately this is the correct answer. With Python 2.7 on Windows 8 even with Lucida Console font enabled it is not possible to represent all characters. I had the luxury of moving to another platform in order to get this to work.

Comment: @ShaneGannon: It is possible to show all characters (at least those that are supported by Lucida Console font) e.g., you could call `CreateProcessW` yourself using `ctypes` module. See [the last link in my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1910275/4279).  Or you could use [`WriteConsoleW()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19206014/4279) to write Unicode from Python directly to Windows console. And if you don't need to support Windows console then just use `'utf-8'` encoding and redirect the output to a file (or another program if it allows to specify its input encoding).

Comment: I don't think Lucida Console font supports 你好. Since I can choose not to use Windows utf-8 works well for me.

Answer (score 2):

Your first try was the best.

You actually converted the 2 unicode characters `u'你好'` (or `u'\u4f60\u597d'`) in UTF8 all that giving `b'\xe4\xbd\xa0\xe5\xa5\xbd'`.

You can control it in IDLE that fully support unicode and where `b'\xe4\xbd\xa0\xe5\xa5\xbd'.decode('utf-8')` gives back `你好`. Another way to control it is to redirect script output to a file and open it with an UTF-8 compatible editor : there again you will see what you want.

But the problem is that Windows console does not support full unicode. It depends on :

- the code page installed - I do not know for Windows 8 but previous versions had poor support for unicode and could display only 256 characters
- the font used in the console - not all fonts have glyphs for all characters.

If you know a code page that contains glyphs for your characters (I don't), you can try to insert it in a console with `chcp` and explicitely encode your unicode string to that. But on my french machine, I do not know how to do ... except by passing by a text file !

As you spoke of ConEmu, I did it a try ... and it works fine with it, with python 3.4 !

```
chcp 65001
py -3
import subprocess
cmd = ['cmd', '/c', 'echo', u'\u4f60\u597d']
subprocess.call(cmd)
```

gives :

```
你好  
0
```

The problem is only in the `cmd.exe` windows !

Comment: Unsure that this is really an answer because I do not say *do that and it will work*, but it gives some hints

Comment: hmm... as an experiment I ran "print b'\xe4\xbd\xa0\xe5\xa5\xbd'.decode('utf-8')" from the python interpreter but all I got back was "õ¢áÕÑ¢". The annoying thing is that, surprise for me, the cmd does not support 你好. But I can still create a folder with this name from the GUI and Conemu. So an API/approach exists somewhere.

Comment: @ShaneGannon : I didn't use ConEmu (seems nice ...) but as it is internally a GUI application, it can have full unicode support like IDLE has. The problem is only for console applications running in a `cmd.exe` window.

Comment: True. So far it looks like cmd does not support unicode properly. Even after switching the font to "Lucida Console" I can only get some Unicode characters to render. E.g. š but not 你好.

Comment: @ShaneGannon : it works fine with ConEmu. See my edit. And I can confirm that ConEmu uses Consolas as do my cmd.exe windows ...

Comment: Gives unusual behaviour with Python 2.7. If I run the above edit from the interpreter then every line I run prints out "LookupError: unknown encoding: cp65001". If I run it from the command line via a script I get 'UnicodeEncodeError'. But one of the main reasons for Python 3 is to fix Unicode. So it's not too surprising that it may behave better,

Comment: @ShaneGannon the problem is that the command window is forced to interpret the byte sequence emitted through `stdout`, and it does that using the code page. `ConEmu` is able to bypass `stdout` for internal commands such as `echo`, and write to the window with Unicode directly. Code page 65001 is supposed to use UTF-8, but there were problems with it and so the Python developers took a long time to get it to work to their satisfaction - that work couldn't be backported to 2.7.