# Python print Unicode character

Tags: python, unicode

I'm making a card game, but I've run into what seems to be an encoding issue. I'm trying to print a card like this:

```
def print(self):
    print("|-------|")
    print("| %s     |" % self.value)
    print("|       |")
    print("|   %s   |" % self.suit.encode("utf-8"))
    print("|       |")
    print("|    %s  |" % self.value)
    print("|-------|")
```

This is what I want:

```
|-------|
| 10    |
|       |
|   ♦   |
|       |
|    10 |
|-------|
```

...but this is what I get:

```
|-------|
| 10    |
|       |
|   b'\xe2\x99\xa6'   |
|       |
|    10 |
|-------|
```

I'm on Windows and Python 3 if that matters.

The value of self.suit can be any of the following:

```
spade = "♠"
heart = "♥"
diamond = "♦"
club = "♣"
```

If I remove the .encode("utf-8") I get this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "main.py", line 79, in <module>
    start()
  File "main.py", line 52, in start
    play()
  File "main.py", line 64, in play
    card.print()
  File "main.py", line 36, in print
    print("|   \u2660   |")
  File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp850.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2660' in position
4: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: what is the value of self.suit? do you use Python 2 or 3?

Comment: With `# -*- coding: utf8 -*-` as the first line of my file, and with both `self.value` changed to `"9"`, and `self.suit.encode("utf-8")` changed to `"♦"`, this is working fine for me building it in Sublime Text 3. what happens if you replace the `self.suit.encode` line with just the character you want?

Comment: @maccartm It works in my IDE (PyCharm) but not in the windows command line.

Comment: @Wahoozel Just tested it on CMD and it's not working for me there either, cygwin worked fine. I'll play around a bit and see what I can find.

Comment: What is your locale encoding?

Comment: chcp 65001 on cmd and then changing my cmd font to Lucida Console will make the diamond show up...now I get an IOError as soon as it prints

Comment: I feel like this is a CMD/Windows issue.

Comment: Sounds like it; did it print with `.encode("utf-8")` at the end or without it?

Comment: might be helpeful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259084/what-encoding-code-page-is-cmd-exe-using

Comment: It is a cmd issue, yes. Your terminal is in code page 850, so you can't print ♦ which doesn't exist in 850. Code page 65001 would work except for it suffers from implementation bugs in Windows. In general the Windows command line is a dead loss for Unicode.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30982765/4447998

Comment: @bobince, try `print(chr(4))` in the Windows console :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This takes advantage of the fact that the OEM code pages in the Windows console print some visible characters for control characters.  The card suits for `cp437` and `cp850` are `chr(3)-chr(6)`.  Python 3 (prior to 3.6) won't print the Unicode character for a black diamond, but it's what you get for U+0004:

```
>>> print('\N{BLACK DIAMOND SUIT}')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python33\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2666' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
>>> print(chr(4))
♦
```

Therefore:

```
#!python3
#coding: utf8
class Card:
    def __init__(self,value,suit):
        self.value = value
        self.suit = suit    # 1,2,3,4 = ♥♦♣♠

    def print(self):
        print("┌───────┐")
        print("| {:<2}    |".format(self.value))
        print("|       |")
        print("|   {}   |".format(chr(self.suit+2)))
        print("|       |")
        print("|    {:>2} |".format(self.value))
        print("└───────┘")
```

Output:

```
>>> x=Card('K',4)
>>> x.print()
┌───────┐
| K     |
|       |
|   ♠   |
|       |
|     K |
└───────┘
>>> x=Card(10,3)
>>> x.print()
┌───────┐
| 10    |
|       |
|   ♣   |
|       |
|    10 |
└───────┘
```

#### Python 3.6 Update

Python 3.6 uses Windows Unicode APIs to print so no need for the control character trick now, and the new format strings can be used:

```
#!python3.6
#coding: utf8
class Card:
    def __init__(self,value,suit):
        self.value = value
        self.suit = '♥♦♣♠'[suit-1] # 1,2,3,4 = ♥♦♣♠

    def print(self):
        print('┌───────┐')
        print(f'| {self.value:<2}    |')
        print('|       |')
        print(f'|   {self.suit}   |')
        print('|       |')
        print(f'|    {self.value:>2} |')
        print('└───────┘')
```

Output:

```
>>> x=Card('10',3)
>>> x.print()
┌───────┐
| 10    |
|       |
|   ♣   |
|       |
|    10 |
└───────┘
```