# Auto newline when print unicode in console, python 3.4

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, unicode, windows-console

I use Python 3.4, the Windows console, and `chcp 65001` (font consolas).

This is my code:

```
print("%s" % "ô ô")
```

result:

```
ô ô
```

But when i print more unicode character, it's auto make a newline:

```
print("%s" % "ô ô ô")

ô ô ô
�


print("%s" % "ô ô ô ô")

ô ô ô ô
ô
```

And my question is:

- Why?
- How to print a unicode string in one line?

Comment: Not reproducing for me in Python 3.4.3 , in windows 7. Are you sure that is the exact code that is reproducing the issue for you? Could it be part of a larger code?

Comment: do you use CMD?, my code is only 2 line: # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- and
print("%s" % "ô ô ô ô")

Comment: Yes i am running from command line, (I ran using a script as well) still same, not sure if someone else can reproduce.

Comment: do you use chcp 65001 and font consolas? , i ran from a file ".py"

Comment: Codepage 65001 (UTF-8) doesn't work in the Windows console. There are various bugs across Windows and C runtime versions. In this case it's returning the number of UTF-16 codes written to the console's internal screen buffer instead of the number of UTF-8 bytes written. Use the wide-character API instead, e.g. via [win-unicode-console](https://github.com/Drekin/win-unicode-console).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows cmd encoding change causes Python crash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/878972/windows-cmd-encoding-change-causes-python-crash) — The crash has been fixed since but printing Unicode strings is indeed still broken.

Comment: Another similar question, although not specifically about python 3 is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30923819/why-python-2-7-on-windows-need-a-space-before-unicode-character-when-print. cp65001 has indeed all sorts of weird bugs.