# What is causing the extra number to be printed in my first Python script? (codepage/unicode issue)

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, codepages

I'm a C programmer learning Python 3 for the first time.  This is my first script.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
print ("Hello World!")
print ("Ä 0196, Ë 0203, Ï 0207, Ö 0214, Ü 0220, Ÿ 0159.")
```

Here is some setup and the output:

```
C:\Users\K\Desktop\Code\Python\Korgan\LearnPythonTheHardWay>chcp 65001
Active code page: 65001

C:\Users\K\Desktop\Code\Python\Korgan\LearnPythonTheHardWay>set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8

C:\Users\K\Desktop\Code\Python\Korgan\LearnPythonTheHardWay>py ex1.py
Hello World!
Ä 0196, Ë 0203, Ï 0207, Ö 0214, Ü 0220, Ÿ 0159.
159.

C:\Users\K\Desktop\Code\Python\Korgan\LearnPythonTheHardWay>
```

It printed an extra "159." and a newline at the end.  Why?

'py' with no arguments:

```
PS C:\Users\K\desktop\code\Python\Korgan\LearnPythonTheHardWay> py
Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:43:06) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Comment: That isn't what I get when I run your program

Comment: please print the output of the following:
env| grep -i ENCODING

Comment: what is the program "py"?  What happens if you run "py" with no arguments?

Comment: @fiacre This is on win8, unfortunately.

Comment: @fiacre I've updated my question to show 'py' with no arguments.

Comment: @intboolstring Do you get the expected output?

Comment: set PYTHONIOENCODING has a typo, but I don't think it is related

Comment: @fiacre what's the typo?

Comment: @KorganRivera, misread it, sorry

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why python 2.7 on Windows need a space before unicode character when print?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30923819/why-python-2-7-on-windows-need-a-space-before-unicode-character-when-print), see also [Python, Unicode, and the Windows console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419/python-unicode-and-the-windows-console). Those questions don't describe the exact same symptoms but have the same underlying issue.

Comment: Since you mention C, you can reproduce that issue with a simple C program using `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows console doesn't support code page 65001 and does a number of weird things when you try, due to underlying character-counting bugs. This affects all applications using the C standard IO interfaces, including Python.

If you really, really need to get Unicode to the console it's possible to work around the problem by calling the Win32-specific console APIs directly instead. See [win_unicode_console](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/win_unicode_console).