# No Chinese characters printed in Haskell

Tags: haskell, unicode-string

For me, the Chinese characters printing is not smooth. Like the `putStrLn` cases:

```
*Main> putStrLn "中文"
- 

*Main> putStrLn "中文!"

-?
```

I then follow a suggestion from  stackoverflow to use `"MyPrint.hs"` to print Chinese characters in output without seeing the character shown. The loaded original `MyPrint` is as following:

```
module MyPrint (myPrint, myShow) where
-- preparing for the 7.6.1
myPrint :: Show a => a -> IO ()
myPrint = putStrLn . myShow

myShow :: Show a => a -> String
myShow x = con (show x) where
   con :: String -> String
   con [] = []
   con li@(x:xs) | x == '\"' = '\"':str++"\""++(con rest)
            | x == '\'' = '\'':char:'\'':(con rest')
            | otherwise = x:con xs where
              (str,rest):_ = reads li
              (char,rest'):_ = reads li
```

In winGHCi, the result  is like this:

```
*MyPrint> myPrint "asf萨芬速读法"
"asf(?"
```

Neither Chinese characters be shown in GHCi. Why and how to overcome it? Thanks!

Comment: The windows console doesn't display Unicode characters correctly. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10779149/unicode-console-i-o-in-haskell-on-windows

Comment: This boils down to exactly the same problem as described in the marked duplicate, but it's a good signpost to the problem as it describes the symptoms much more directly and visually.