# GHCi: incorrect text output despite the right font and codepage

Tags: powershell, haskell, cmd, ghci, codepages

Windows 8.1 x64 Russian.

I create and fill the `%AppData%\ghc\ghci.conf` file:

```
:! title GHCi (Haskell interpreter)
putStrLn $ replicate 30 '*'
putStrLn "© Андрей Бушман, 2014" -- The sample of some not English chars...
:set prompt "\x03BB: "
```

This file has the `UTF-8 without BOM` encoding. I run `ghci` via `Cmd.exe` and `PowerShell.exe`. I set necessary font and codepage before. But I get unexpected result: incorrect text output. Why I get it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

UPD

I can resave my `ghci.conf` file with `Windows 1251` encoding and add the `:! chcp 1251`at first row:

```
:! chcp 1251
:! title GHCi (Haskell interpreter)
putStrLn $ replicate 30 '*'
putStrLn "© Андрей Бушман, 2014" -- The sample of not English chars...
:set prompt "\x03BB: "
```

Now I see the correct result:

[image]

But why it doesn't work when I save with `UTF-8` or `UTF-8 without BOM` encodings and set 65001 codepage?

Also... I get incorrect text **in the title** when I use the *cyrillic* chars:

```
:! chcp 1251
-- Cyrillic in te title:
:! title GHCi (Интерпретатор Haskell)
putStrLn $ replicate 30 '*'
putStrLn "© Андрей Бушман, 2014 (\"авторские права\" на данное сообщение ;) )"
:set prompt "\x03BB: "
```

[image]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably related to the following question:
[Unicode console I/O in Haskell on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10779149/unicode-console-i-o-in-haskell-on-windows)

Btw, setting the font in the console will not affect what codepage is used.