# GHCi on Windows: how to read Unicode input from console?

Tags: windows, powershell, haskell, cmd

How to make the following code work with Unicode (CJK) in Command Prompt/LameShell?

```
main = getLine >>= putStrLn
```

(Windows 8.1, Haskell Platform 2014)

No, `chcp 65001` doesn't work, nor `chcp 10000`.

No, I don't want to change System Local (Control Panel/Clock, Language, and Region/Language/Change date, time, or number formats/Administrative) from English(United States) to others.

Yes, I have set font to Lucida Console.

I've tried ConEmu/Cmder/Console2, they all said "Exception: : hGetLine: end of file". I also tried Emacs, (I use Vim), it didn't crash, but I always get spaces, no matter what I input.

Patch GHC and recompile it is acceptable, if there is no other way.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `hSetEncoding` from in `System.IO`?

Comment: Don't work. After `chcp 65001`, `hGetEncoding stdin` already gives me `Just UTF-8`, I just did a `hSetEncoding stdin utf8` anyway, no luck.

Comment: I've had this problem on CentOS before and I had it solved with hSetEncoding. It doesn't appear to be working in my Windows 8 either.... It's really bizzare. Perhaps patching GHC is the correct way to deal with it for now.

Comment: Thanks anyway. This seems to be an obvious bug, I just don't believe that it hasn't been fixed already.

Comment: This might be a duplicate of [Unicode console I/O in Haskell on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10779149/unicode-console-i-o-in-haskell-on-windows).

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell supports UTF natively.  Assuming I understand your example (`main = getLine >>= putStrLn`) properly:

```
$var = Read-Host
Write "$var"
```

Or simply:

```
Read-Host
```