# How do you get getLine to accept unicode characters?

Tags: windows, haskell, unicode, encoding, console

When running the following code

```
do line <- getLine
   putStrLn line
```

or,

```
getLine >>= putStrLn
```

And, after

```
 getLine >>= putStrLn
```

entering

```
µ
```

one encounters this output:

```
⠀
```

Now, I already tried `chcp 65001` beforehand, which doesn't work, and the encoding of `stdin` is `utf8`.

An examination without `putStrLn` shows:

```
 getLine
µ
'\NIL'
```

My environment:
Windows 10 Version 10.0.17134 Build 17134
Lenovo ideapad 510-15IKB
BIOS Version LENOVO 3JCN30WW
GHCi v 8.2.2

How can this be solved?

EDIT: Specifically, the following sequence of actions causes this:

1. Open `cmd`
2. Type `chcp 65001`
3. Type `ghci`
4. Type `getLine >>= putStrLn`
5. Type `µ`

However, the following does not:

1. Search for `ghci`
2. Open `ghci.exe` at `%PROGRAMS%\Haskell Platform\8.2.2\bin`
3. Repeat 4-5.

NOTE: `%PROGRAMS%` is not a real environment variable.

EDIT: As requested, the output of `GHC.IO.Encoding.getLocaleEncoding`:

```
UTF-8
```

Also, the output of `System.IO.hGetEncoding stdin`:

```
Just UTF-8
```

(when using `chcp 65001`)

EDIT: The character is U+00B5. I am using a German keyboard, system locale Germany, language setting English, Keyboard language ENG with German layout.

Comment: This is on Windows?

Comment: This works as expected for me. Could you provide more details about your environment?

Comment: MacOS X with ghc 8.0.2 works as expected.

Comment: Are you sure the stdin you’re giving is utf8 and not utf16? And is that letter a mu (U+03BC) or a micro sign (U+00B5)?

Comment: In the faulty `ghci` session, what does `GHC.IO.Encoding.getLocaleEncoding` say?

Comment: You may want to search the GHC Trac for related tickets. I imagine you're not the first to encounter such a problem. If you can't find something, open a ticket. FYI: At the moment, the go-to expert on Windows-specific problems seems to be Tamar Christina. He usually uses the handle Phyx or Phyx- online.

Comment: @Mark Neu, just in case you are really curious to see a workaround, I made an edit to my answer with a minimal working solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Console input/output is utterly broken on Windows and has been for some time now. Here is the top ticket that tracks all the issues related to IO on Windows:
https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/11394

I believe, these two tickets describe best the behavior that you are experiencing:

- https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/10542
- https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/4471

The only work around right now is to manually use Windows API for dealing console output/input, which is a pain of its own.

**EDIT**

So, just for the hell of it I decided to endure some of that pain. :)

Here is the output of the code below:

```
====
Input: µ
Output: µ
====
```

This is by no means a fully correct or a safe solution, but it does work:

```
module Main where

import Control.Monad
import System.IO
import Foreign.Ptr
import Foreign.ForeignPtr
import Foreign.C.String
import Foreign.C.Types
import Foreign.Storable

import System.Win32
import System.Win32.Types
import Graphics.Win32.Misc

foreign import ccall unsafe "windows.h WriteConsoleW"
  c_WriteConsoleW :: HANDLE -> LPWSTR -> DWORD -> LPDWORD -> LPVOID -> IO BOOL

foreign import ccall unsafe "windows.h ReadConsoleW"
  c_ReadConsoleW :: HANDLE -> LPWSTR -> DWORD -> LPDWORD -> LPVOID -> IO BOOL

-- | Read n characters from a handle, which should be a console stdin
hwGetStrN :: Int -> Handle -> IO String
hwGetStrN maxLen hdl = do
  withCWStringLen (Prelude.replicate maxLen '\NUL') $ \(cstr, len) -> do
    lpNumberOfCharsWrittenForeignPtr <- mallocForeignPtr
    withHandleToHANDLE hdl $ \winHANDLE ->
      withForeignPtr lpNumberOfCharsWrittenForeignPtr $ \lpNumberOfCharsRead -> do
        c_ReadConsoleW winHANDLE cstr (fromIntegral len) lpNumberOfCharsRead nullPtr
        numWritten <- peek lpNumberOfCharsRead
        peekCWStringLen (cstr, fromIntegral numWritten)

-- | Write a string to a handle, which should be a console stdout or stderr.
hwPutStr :: Handle -> String -> IO ()
hwPutStr hdl str = do
  void $ withCWStringLen str $ \(cstr, len) -> do
    lpNumberOfCharsWrittenForeignPtr <- mallocForeignPtr
    withHandleToHANDLE hdl $ \winHANDLE ->
      withForeignPtr lpNumberOfCharsWrittenForeignPtr $ \ lpNumberOfCharsWritten ->
      c_WriteConsoleW winHANDLE cstr (fromIntegral len) lpNumberOfCharsWritten nullPtr

main :: IO ()
main = do
  hwPutStr stdout "====\nInput: "
  str <- hwGetStrN 10 stdin
  hwPutStr stdout "Output: "
  hwPutStr stdout str
  hwPutStr stdout "====\n"
```

**EDIT 2**

@dfeuer asked me to list things that are unsafe, incorrect or incomplete with that answer. I only really code on Linux, so I am not a Windows programmer, but here are the things that pop into my mind that would need to be changed before that code could be used in a real program:

- The most important part is that code will work only with console handles, which can be determined by [`GetConsoleMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolemode) API call.
- For other type of handles the code above will do nothing, eg. if used with pipes or file handles, which has its own issues with encoding, but that is a totally separate issue.
- API call failures aren't accounted for. So we'd have to check if a call was successful by looking at the returned `BOOL`, and whenever it's not use [`GetLastError`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms679360) to report the error back to the user.
- Functions implemented above are very limited, there are no checks on how much they've actually read/wrote to/from buffer. For that reason `hwGetStrN` can only handle `n` characters, so recursive call would be required in order to get behavior similar to `hGetLine`
- Do all the sanity checks, eg. `DWORD` is `Word32`, so `fromIntegral len` call is susceptible to integer overflow, which is both incorrect and unsafe.
- FFI calls must be `stdcall` on 32bit OS, while `ccall` for `x86_64`, so some CPP is necessary

Comment: Can you point out in your answer what specifically is likely to be incomplete, incorrect, or unsafe, if you have an inkling?

Comment: @dfeuer, This sort of functionality should certainly in `base`, and I can't recommend using the sample code I provided. Regardless of that I've updated the answer with the things I can think of that would have to be fixed if that code is to be used anywhere.

Comment: Ah, look, with a little bit of searching I found a similar, but more extensive solution proposed 6 years ago :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10779149/unicode-console-i-o-in-haskell-on-windows