# Print an arabic unicode string in Python(x,y)

Tags: python, unicode, pythonxy

I have an Arabic unicode string that I want to print in Python (using Python(x,y) on Windows 7), but I can't get it to print, only the unicode representation is printed out.

The string is defined as:

```
ss = u'\u0647\u0630\u0627 \u0647\u0648 \u0627\u0644\u062d\u0644 \u0627\u0644\u0648\u062d\u064a\u062f \u0644\u0644\u0645\u0634\u0643\u0644\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u062a\u064a \u0646\u0648\u0627\u062c\u0647\u0647\u0627'
```

and should look like this: "هذا هو الحل الوحيد للمشكلة التي نواجهها"

When I try `print`, it gives the following error

```
print ss
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: character maps to <undefined>
```

When I encode the string, say with cp1256 (Windows Arabic), it gives a wrong representation:

```
print ss.encode('cp1256')
åÐÇ åæ ÇáÍá ÇáæÍíÏ ááãÔßáÉ ÇáÊí äæÇÌååÇ
```

I have looked at several questions here related to printing unicode from Python on Windows, but nothing seems to work.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
I am using Spyder IDE (bundled with Python(x,y) on Windows 7).

**UPDATE2:**
I already tried all the solutions in the "duplicate" questions, but none worked.

Comment: @ecatmur I tried the solutions on that page, and none worked

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39528462/5284370) out.

Answer (score 1):

Your console is configured to display codepage 1252 (Latin 1), which indeed cannot handle your codepoints. Switch your console to a different codepage that *can* display the characters.

You could switch to 1256:

```
chcp 1256
```

or switch to 65001 (the UTF-8 codepage), which should be able to handle *any* unicode codepoint. You may have to switch the font used for your console though; Lucida Sans is reported to display most of Unicode.

Comment: switching to chcp 1256 didn't solve the problem, still get unreadable/wrong characters. Switching to 65001 gives an error in the python interpreter:

LookupError: unknown encoding: cp65001

Comment: @malaa: What python version do you use?

Comment: @malaa: See [Windows cmd encoding change causes Python crash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/878972/3259271)

Comment: @malaa: Since I don't use windows myself, it is harder for me to discern what versions support the 65001 codepage. Does the linked message help?

Comment: no, tried the solutions there and none worked. thanks :)

Comment: @malaa: The [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3259271/100297) that describes how to alias 65001 to UTF-8?

Comment: Tried that also, but didn't work

Comment: See https://github.com/Drekin/win-unicode-console. It's a package solving the problem. You can also read the explanation of the problem. The package is also on pypi (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/win_unicode_console) and can be installed using pip.