# printing unicode for bengali

Tags: python, unicode, goslate, bengali

I'm using `goslate` for google translate API

I can translate Bengali to Engliash -

```
>>> import goslate

>>> gs = goslate.Goslate()
>>> S = gs.translate("ভাল", 'en')
>>> S

good
```

But, problem in arising when I want to translate English to Bengali.

```
>>> import goslate

>>> gs = goslate.Goslate()
>>> S = gs.translate("good", 'bn')
>>> S
```

Eoor:

```
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2:     character maps to <undefined>
```

What should I do?

```
print repr(S)
output: u'\u09ad\u09be\u09b2'

print("ভাল")
output: à¦­à¦¾à¦²

print(u"ভাল") # this gives UnicodeEncodeError
```

Comment: check this question, i think it might answer yours as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15162398/print-an-arabic-unicode-string-in-pythonx-y

Comment: no. Thats not helping

Comment: show us `repr(S)` or `ascii(S)` (Python 3). It is probably unrelated to `goslate`. What happens if you `print(u"ভাল")`?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, I modified my post as you say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me

```
#coding: utf-8

from sys import setdefaultencoding, getdefaultencoding

d=getdefaultencoding()
if d != "utf-8":
    setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
st="ভাল"
f=open('test.txt','w')
f.write(st.encode('utf-8'))
f.close()
if d != "utf-8":
    setdefaultencoding(d)
```

This prints "ভাল" as expected.
`print st.encode('utf-8')` works too.

Comment: It should work actually. But, this gives me `à¦­à¦¾à¦²`. What should I need to do? may be some changes I need in IDLE?

Comment: Even `#coding: ...` doesn't help??

Comment: `#coding` this is a comment ?

Comment: Throw IDLE away and use console for output. That may help.

Comment: @AerofoilKite, `coding` is special directive.

Comment: I need to store this "ভাল" in text file.

Comment: it won't work if the environment uses character encoding different from utf-8

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, okay, I used `encode()`, this won't work too? @AerofoilKite, just `write()` it and that's all.

Comment: May be your technique is working on your machine. ? Something is wrong with my software. I'm using spyder

Comment: @AerofoilKite, try to execute this full script I gave using the command prompt (`cmd.exe` or Terminal on Mac OS)

Comment: the `.encode()` call leads to `UnicodeDecodeError` (do not encode bytes). `st` should be a Unicode string that you can print directly.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, _it doesn't_ on my system. `#coding: utf-8` gives opportunity to use any Unicode character in script.

Comment: the source code encoding (declared using `#coding: utf-8`) has nothing to do with the error. It is easy to demonstrate even with ascii source code: `b'\xe0\xa6\xad'.encode('utf-8')`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, this code _works on my system_. So it does _on the OP's one_.

Comment: I don't see any evidence of that. It won't work on a typical Python 2  installation where `sys.getdefaultencoding()` returns  `'ascii'`.

Comment: it won't work (`ImportError`). You can't just call `sys.setdefaultencoding` and for a good reason. It hides bugs and may break 3rd party-libraries that don't expect non-default encoding.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, I can do it. Maybe you're using some old Python version.

Comment: @ForceBru: You can do it because your installation is non-standard (customized). Somewhere in your startup files you have `reload(sys)`. The standard installation has no `sys.setdefaultencoding()`. Here's [the place where it is removed](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/site.py#l542)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, what are we talking about? Did this answer help the OP? Yes. No problem then.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely unrelated to `goslate`. Your issue is to make `print u'\u09ad\u09be\u09b2'` to work when the Unicode characters can't be represented using the console character encoding.

You either need to change the encoding to the one that can represent the Unicode characters such as utf-8 or use Unicode API such as `WriteConsoleW` assuming you are on Windows -- if you are not on Windows then just configure your environment to use utf-8.

[`WriteConsoleW` usage is complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/878972/4279) though there is a [simple to use `win_unicode_console` package on Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28522085/4279). The latter link also shows how  to save the printed Unicode text to a file (print Unicode, set `PYTHONIOENCODING`).