# How to write utf8 to standard output in a way that works with python2 and python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, stdout

I want to write a non-ascii character, lets say `→` to standard output. The tricky part seems to be that some of the data that I want to concatenate to that string is read from json. Consider the follwing simple json document:

```
{"foo":"bar"}
```

I include this because if I just want to print `→` then it seems enough to simply write:

```
print("→")
```

and it will do the right thing in python2 and python3.

So I want to print the value of `foo` together with my non-ascii character `→`. The only way I found to do this such that it works in both, python2 and python3 is:

```
getattr(sys.stdout, 'buffer', sys.stdout).write(data["foo"].encode("utf8")+u"→".encode("utf8"))
```

or

```
getattr(sys.stdout, 'buffer', sys.stdout).write((data["foo"]+u"→").encode("utf8"))
```

It is important to not miss the `u` in front of `→` because otherwise a `UnicodeDecodeError` will be thrown by python2.

Using the `print` function like this:

```
print((data["foo"]+u"→").encode("utf8"), file=(getattr(sys.stdout, 'buffer', sys.stdout)))
```

doesnt seem to work because python3 will complain `TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface`.

Did I find the best way or is there a better option? Can I make the print function work?

Comment: So `print(data['foo'] + u'→')` doesn't work?

Comment: @user2357112: Not on my machine.

Comment: For your last example that calls `print`, in Python 3 encoding the string returns `bytes`. Since `print` requires a string, it calls the `__str__` method, which for `bytes` just returns a repr, i.e. `str("→".encode()) == "b'\\xe2\\x86\\x92'"`. Next `print` writes this useless repr to the `file`, but the `BufferedWriter` requires an object that supports the buffer interface, such as `bytes`.

Comment: @eryksun thank you! As `print()` is able to print all kinds of datatypes without explicit conversion to `str` I didnt think it would choke on `bytes`.

Comment: Printing has to first get an object as a string. This doesn't choke on Python 3 `bytes`. Decoding `bytes` using a default encoding would be wrong in general, since a `bytes` object isn't necessarily text. I just meant the repr string is "useless" for your needs. What choked is trying to print to a `BufferedWriter`, e.g. `print('abc', file=sys.stdout.buffer)`.

Comment: You can try putting this at top on your Script "# coding=utf8"

Comment: @EstebanOlate: That won't ever fix unicode problems with printing. Please don't cargo cult the source encoding hint when you don't understand what it does.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Wait, what? I keep getting notifications... I think you're confusing me for josch? :)

Comment: @anon: ick, I am. Re-directing the comments.

Comment: @anon: that said, why do *you* claim `print(data['foo'] + u'→')` doesn't work on your machine? **That works perfectly fine** in a properly configured environment.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I have a deleted answer. It doesn't work unless I put the proper encoding: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`.

Comment: What JSON library are you using? What *full* traceback do you get when you use `print(data['foo'] + u'→')`? There should be **no need** to go to these lengths; Python is perfectly capable of printing Unicode to a properly configured terminal or console.

Comment: @anon: sure, you need to make sure that the `u'→'` string literal is correctly interpreted.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: He didn't have it in his question, so I thought it might have been a probable cause, but it wasn't so I deleted it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters `print(data['foo'] + u'→')` doesn't work on Windows. This has everything to do with `sys.stdout.encoding` and the terminal/shell you're trying to print to.

Comment: @snapshoe: That is a **different** issue, and a duplicate question if that is the case here. No amount of raw UTF-8 writing will fix that issue either.

Comment: @snapshoe: this is why I explicitly state that things work for *a properly configured terminal or console*, to address exactly that issue.

Answer (score 3):

The most concise I could come up with is the following, which you may be able to make more concise with a few convenience functions (or even replacing/overriding the print function):

```
# -*- coding=utf-8 -*-
import codecs
import os
import sys

# if you include the -*- coding line, you can use this
output = 'bar' + u'→'
# otherwise, use this
output = 'bar' + b'\xe2\x86\x92'.decode('utf-8')

if sys.stdout.encoding == 'UTF-8':
    print(output)
else:
    output += os.linesep
    if sys.version_info[0] >= 3:
        sys.stdout.buffer.write(bytes(output.encode('utf-8')))
    else:
        codecs.getwriter('utf-8')(sys.stdout).write(output)
```

The best option is using the -*- encoding line, which allows you to use the actual character in the file. But if for some reason, you can't use the encoding line, it's still possible to accomplish without it.

This (both with and without the encoding line) works on Linux (Arch) with python 2.7.7 and 3.4.1.
It also works if the terminal's encoding is not UTF-8. (On Arch Linux, I just change the encoding by using a different LANG environment variable.)

```
LANG=zh_CN python test.py
```

It also *sort of* works on Windows, which I tried with 2.6, 2.7, 3.3, and 3.4. By *sort of*, I mean I could get the `'→'` character to display only on a mintty terminal. On a cmd terminal, that character would display as `'ΓåÆ'`. (There may be something simple I'm missing there.)

Comment: With regard to Windows only sort of working, would changing `'utf-8'` to `sys.stdout.encoding` print any better?

Comment: No. That would be the same as simply doing a print. If you're not changing the encoding, `sys.stdout.encoding` is the one it uses, which is why all the work to change it from it's default.

Comment: As an experiment, try the code [here](http://pastebin.com/DM3hX3Yp). It will show the effect of the encoding used on a terminal for all available encodings-- for ones that don't throw exceptions. I ran this on Windows & Linux, 2.7 & 3.4.

Comment: I cannot stress enough how important it is to ensure your terminal or console is correctly configured. It should not be Python's job to ensure this. Personally, I'd use `output = output.encode('utf-8')`, `try:`, `sys.stdout.buffer.write(output)`, `except AttributeError:`, `sys.stdout.write(output)`; `codecs.getwriter()` is overkill here, and you need to test for *features*, not versions. You can use the `io` module in Python 2 as well so `sys.stdout` could actually have the `.buffer` attribute there too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Is there a tutorial or reference on how to correctly configure a console/terminal (cmd/powershell/other?) on Windows?

Comment: For Python 2 [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/878972/windows-cmd-encoding-change-causes-python-crash) is very thorough. I believe that for Python 3, the right code page Just Works.

Comment: For the console itself, see [this post on what codepage and font to use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how).

Comment: The real beef here is `codecs.getwriter('utf-8')(sys.stdout)`.  It took me a detour through [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1169209/874188) to appreciate this.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to print to `sys.stdout.buffer`, then the following should print fine to `sys.stdout`.  I tried it in both Python 2.7 and 3.4, and it seemed to work fine:

```
# -*- coding=utf-8 -*-
print("bar" + u"→")
```

Comment: This does not work if `sys.stdout.encoding != "UTF-8"`, such as on Windows.

Comment: @snapshoe It is obvious that it will not be _displayed_ properly if the output goes to something with limited capabilities. But Python does write to the output in UTF-8, and the OP wanted to send the output in a file, it seems.

Comment: @rds I don't see any mention of outputting to a file. I do see mentioned everywhere, including the title of the post, about printing to stdout.