# Python 2 and 3 compatible way to print unicode that degrades gracefully

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, unicode, python-unicode

What's the best way to do proper output of non-ascii characters that's Python 2 and 3 compatible? Is it this?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from __future__ import print_function
print("ȧƈƈḗƞŧḗḓ uʍop-ǝpısdn ŧḗẋŧ ƒǿř ŧḗşŧīƞɠ")
```

One problem with that approach is it doesn't degrade gracefully in situations where output is limited (for example) to `ascii` or `latin1`. The default behavior is to raise an exception like:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-7: ordinal not in range(128)
```

...I'd much prefer escaping such as the ['replace' or 'backslashreplace' error handling methods](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codec-base-classes). Is there a way to configure `sys.stdout` to use one of these methods? Is that a reasonable thing to do?

Unicode encoding in Python has been discussed a lot on StackOverflow, for example: 
[How to write utf8 to standard output in a way that works with python2 and python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944976/how-to-write-utf8-to-standard-output-in-a-way-that-works-with-python2-and-python/24104423), and [snapshoe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24104423/199166) and a helpful [comment by Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944976/how-to-write-utf8-to-standard-output-in-a-way-that-works-with-python2-and-python/24104423#comment37323552_24104423). Also [Setting the correct encoding when piping stdout in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492483/setting-the-correct-encoding-when-piping-stdout-in-python).

But I still don't see a clear "best" way, especially with regard to handling errors gracefully.