# Printing unicode in python

Tags: python, unicode

I'm trying to run the `fix_bad_unicode` found [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578243-repair-common-unicode-mistakes-after-theyve-been-m/) with the addition:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    A = fix_bad_unicode(u'hell€')
    print A
```

I get an error at the print statement:

`UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u20ac' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)` in sublime text's console

and

`UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u20ac' in position 4: character maps to <undefined>` in the windows command prompt

I have tried changing to lucida console font.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: Also, `print "€"` in the python prompt gives `?`

Comment: This is quite tricky in Windows isn't it. This is also the subject of a million earlier questions here.

Comment: Where is this answer?

Comment: This question might be useful too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/878972/windows-cmd-encoding-change-causes-python-crash/3259271