# Installing Tensorflow - not supported wheel

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have installed Python version 3.5 and 3.6 and anaconda.

The following error occures when trying to install tensorflow following the steps here
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows
unsing anaconda

(tensorflow) C:> pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl

tensorflow-1.0.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

As I am new to Python, I do not know how to circumvent this probelm.
I am using Win10 with 64bit.

Thanks a lot and best,

Martin

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I ran into the same difficulties with the same error. It seems to be that Python 3.6 isn't immediately supported and found a sort of workaround [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6999) (note that this involves installing Python 3.5 which I did not already have installed, I don't know if this should be done a different way if its already installed):

> If you are using anaconda distribution, you can do the following to use python 3.5 on the new environment "tensorflow":
>
> ```
> conda create --name tensorflow python=3.5
> activate tensorflow
> conda install jupyter
> conda install scipy
> pip install tensorflow
> \# or
> \# pip install tensorflow-gpu
> ```
>
> It is important to add `python=3.5` at the end of the first line, because it will install Python 3.5.

If you've already created the tensorflow environment (the `conda create` step), you'll have to delete it and start over. Otherwise, you'll run into an error "`CondaValueError: Value error: prefix already exists: C:\[your environment location]`" (If you run into the unsupported wheel error, then you probably created the environment already.)

To delete your previous environment, according to the [Conda Cheat Sheet](http://file:///C:/Users/jimfh/Downloads/conda-cheatsheet.pdf), you first deactivate from `(tensor flow)` if needed by calling `deactivate`, then call `conda remove --prefix ~/bioenvcopy --all`. For `~/bioenvcopy` I believe you use the tensorflow environment path. The location can be found by calling `conda info --envs` (citing the cheat sheet once again). Mine, for example, was `conda remove --prefix ~/Anaconda3/envs/tensorflow`

I successfully used this work around on Windows 10.

This solution probably be obsolete when 3.6 is supported.

Comment: i encounter this problem (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35176270/python-2-7-lookuperror-unknown-encoding-cp65001) when `conda install scipy`, run `set PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8` before running `conda install scipy`, solved the problem.

Comment: This is really great! Thanks for providing the solution!

Comment: Works well though I replaced `pip install tensorflow` with `conda install tensorflow` and it seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

Creating the tensorflow env without the correct python version did not work for me. So I had to do the following, which worked...

```
>deactivate tensorflow # start by deactivating the existing tensorflow env
>conda env remove -n tensorflow # remove the env

>conda create -n tensorflow python=3.5
>activate tensorflow
```

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling everything (python, etc.) and try again using the cmd only, not git bash or PowerShell.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9264

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem in windows 10 and python 3.6
so i navigated to anaconda navigator ( just search anaconda navigator in start search).

in the Environment tab you can create/delete your environments.
just create an environment, name it tensorflow and choose python 3.5 as python version.

then you can activate tensorflow in your command line:

```
activate tensorflow
```

and install tensorflow with :

```
pip install tensorflow #or tensowrlow-gpu
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after hours of searching, I found that to save yourself from installing error problem in tensorflow. The convenient way for installing tensorflow is by creating a virtual environment in Conda with `python 3.5.2` and using [`Conda-forge`](https://github.com/conda-forge/tensorflow-feedstock). This is done by running this commands:

1. `conda create -n tensorflow python=3.5.2`
2. `activate tensorflow`
3. `conda config --add channels conda-forge`
4. `conda install tensorflow`

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the 64-bit version of Python 3.6.8:

https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.8/python-3.6.8-amd64.exe

I was getting the same error with the same OS and that's what fixed it. Apparently Tensorflow doesn't work on 32-bit Python even if your OS is 64-bit.

Answer (score -2):

In Anaconda prompt, follow the instruction on [Installing with Anaconda](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows),

1. `conda create -n tensorflow`
2. `activate tensorflow`

Then the third step is a little different, try:

3. `pip install tensorflow`

This should work, good luck! If anything wrong happens, please let me know.

Comment: I don't believe this works, I think the problem is python 3.6 support.