# Tensorflow installation problems in Windows

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I went through the official documentation to install tensorflow from https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows but I always get this error.

```
tensorflow-1.0.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

for executing

"`pip3 install tensorflow-1.0.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl`"

or

"`pip install tensorflow-1.0.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl`"

I did update pip to 9.1 but I still get

`"You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 9.0.1 is available."` warning.

I have windows 7 64 bit with Python 2.7 & 3.5 both at 64 bit.

P.S. I have referred [Installing tensorflow on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43069519/installing-tensorflow-on-windows) , [tensorflow installation problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35252888/tensorflow-installation-problems)

But they were of no help.

P.P.S. :- I executed the pep425 tags command & I these libs :-

```
[('cp35', 'none', 'win_amd64'), ('py3', 'none', 'win_amd64'), ('cp35', 'none',
any'), ('cp3', 'none', 'any'), ('cp34', 'none', 'any'), ('cp33', 'none', 'any')
 ('cp32', 'none', 'any'), ('cp31', 'none', 'any'), ('cp30', 'none', 'any'), ('py
35', 'none', 'any'), ('py3', 'none', 'any'), ('py34', 'none', 'any'), ('py33',
none', 'any'), ('py32', 'none', 'any'), ('py31', 'none', 'any'), ('py30', 'none
, 'any')]
```

Comment: Maybe related: (1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43069519/installing-tensorflow-on-windows and (2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42755129/installing-tensorfow-not-supported-wheel

Comment: Did you try running `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` as the error message suggests?

Comment: @AlexandrePassos yep i did

Comment: It seems like your upgraded pip installation somehow didn't get picked up. Could it be on a different python version (2 vs 3)?

Answer (score 0):

The error itself is that you are installing a non supported wheel. The other logs about the `pip` version are just warnings that won't necessarily prevent TF installation in this case.

The problem is most likely due a conflict with your two Python installations, as TensorFlow on Windows is only compatible with Python 3.5 64-bit.

If are sure this issue of both versions is isolated and not affecting the installation try doing with the PYPI TensorFlow packages through `pip install tensorflow` and `tensorflow-gpu` for enabled GPU support. If it's a problem with the URL wheel it will yield a different result.

As a last resource download the last stable [nightly build](http://ci.tensorflow.org/view/Nightly/job/nightly-win/) and install with it but my guess is there is there is a conflict between TensorFlow and your two different versions Python installations.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using

> > pip install tensorflow-1.0.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl

make sure of the following

You have python version 3.5 64 bit installed.

> > python --version

Pip supports all the tags in wheel file name. To check this run python shell and then import pip

> > import pip

Then run the following command

> > pip.pep425tags.get_supported()

Now output should contain **cp35, cp35m, win_amd64**, as these are the tags wheel  in file name.

Your pip version does not support **cp35m**. You can either upgrade pip using

> > pip install --upgrade pip

If this does not work. Uninstall python and reinstall 3.5.2 (this worked for me).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using a 64bit architecture(Python interpreter and the machine you use). Tensorflow does not support 32bit architecture.

Answer (score 0):

! python -m pip install tensorflow --upgrade

After several tries, I updated tensorflow with this command it worked for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).