# gsutil command crashes every time on Windows 10

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gsutil, google-cloud-sdk

Whenever I run some gsutil command, for example `gsutil components update`, it exits with this error:

```
ERROR: gcloud crashed (LookupError): unknown encoding: cp65001

If you would like to report this issue, please run the following command:
  gcloud feedback

To check gcloud for common problems, please run the following command:
  gcloud info --run-diagnostics
```

Running `gloud info --diagnostics` as it suggests also fails with the same error:

```
Network diagnostic detects and fixes local network connection issues.
Checking network connection...failed.
ERROR: gcloud crashed (LookupError): unknown encoding: cp65001
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

I've tried setting PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8 ([Python 2.7 : LookupError: unknown encoding: cp65001](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35176270/python-2-7-lookuperror-unknown-encoding-cp65001)) but it didn't help, I think gsutil uses its own Python and it might be ignoring/resetting this variable.

**Edit:**

I'm using Powershell, it already has UTF-8 set as the encoding:

```
[Console]::OutputEncoding


BodyName          : utf-8
EncodingName      : Unicode (UTF-8)
HeaderName        : utf-8
WebName           : utf-8
WindowsCodePage   : 1200
IsBrowserDisplay  : True
IsBrowserSave     : True
IsMailNewsDisplay : True
IsMailNewsSave    : True
IsSingleByte      : False
EncoderFallback   : System.Text.EncoderReplacementFallback
DecoderFallback   : System.Text.DecoderReplacementFallback
IsReadOnly        : True
CodePage          : 65001
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstalling the Cloud SDK with "Bundled Python" unchecked did the trick for me. I have Python 2.7 installed independently.

Answer (score 0):

Just run:

```
set PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8
```