# LookupError: unknown encoding: 65001 in anaconda

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmqcc.jpg)

How i can solve this solution .I'm newbie in python on anaconda

Version
Jupyter5.5.0
window 10 64 bit
anaconda 5.2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 2.7 : LookupError: unknown encoding: cp65001](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35176270/python-2-7-lookuperror-unknown-encoding-cp65001)

Answer (score 1):

```
# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\oztur\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 105, in main
        return activator_main()
      File "C:\Users\oztur\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\activate.py", line 838, in main
        print(activator.execute(), end='')
      File "C:\Users\oztur\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\activate.py", line 110, in execute
        return getattr(self, self.command)()
      File "C:\Users\oztur\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\activate.py", line 88, in activate
        return self._finalize(self._yield_commands(builder_result), self.tempfile_extension)
      File "C:\Users\oztur\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\activate.py", line 78, in _finalize
        tf.write(ensure_binary(self.command_join.join(commands)))
      File "C:\Users\oztur\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\activate.py", line 536, in ensure_binary
        return value.encode(encoding)
    LookupError: unknown encoding: 65001
```

In the activate.py in line 536 I did this `return value.encode(encoding="utf-8")` It worked for me.