# LookupError: unknown encoding: string_escape when running scons command

Tags: python, scons, iotivity

I am following this tutorial to build the IoTivity Base Android API:

https://wiki.iotivity.org/android_build_instructions#android_example_apps

I downloaded the IoTivity project from here:

https://iotivity.org/downloads

I am at the step where I use the command to build IoTivity for Android:

```
scons TARGET_OS=android
```

And I get the output:

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ... LookupError: unknown encoding:
string_escape:   File
"C:\Users\Darius\Downloads\iotivity-1.3.1.tar\iotivity-1.3.1\iotivity-1.3.1\SConstruct",
line 28:
    SConscript('build_common/SConscript')   File "c:\users\darius\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\scons\SCons\Script\SConscript.py",
line 667:
    return method(*args, **kw)   File "c:\users\darius\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\scons\SCons\Script\SConscript.py",
line 604:
    return _SConscript(self.fs, *files, **subst_kw)   File "c:\users\darius\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\scons\SCons\Script\SConscript.py",
line 285:
    call_stack[-1].globals)   File "C:\Users\Darius\Downloads\iotivity-1.3.1.tar\iotivity-1.3.1\iotivity-1.3.1\build_common\SConscript",
line 559:
    user_prefix = env.get('BUILD_DIR').encode('string_escape')
```

I am on a Windows machine, using Command Prompt.

I tried the solutions in this post:

[Python 2.7 : LookupError: unknown encoding: cp65001](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35176270/python-2-7-lookuperror-unknown-encoding-cp65001)

But it did not help. I am new to Python. Can someone help?

**EDIT**

After changing to Python 2.7.16, I now get this output instead:

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...

*********************** Error ************************
*                                                    *
* Please make sure that 7-zip is in your System PATH *
*                                                    *
******************************************************

NameError: name 'host_arch' is not defined:   File
"C:\Users\Darius\Downloads\iotivity-1.3.1.tar\iotivity-1.3.1\iotivity-1.3.1\SConstruct",
line 28:
    SConscript('build_common/SConscript')   File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scons\SCons\Script\SConscript.py", line
667:
    return method(*args, **kw)   File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scons\SCons\Script\SConscript.py", line
604:
    return _SConscript(self.fs, *files, **subst_kw)   File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scons\SCons\Script\SConscript.py", line
285:
    call_stack[-1].globals)   File "C:\Users\Darius\Downloads\iotivity-1.3.1.tar\iotivity-1.3.1\iotivity-1.3.1\build_common\SConscript",
line 795:
    env.SConscript(target_os + '/SConscript')   File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scons\SCons\Script\SConscript.py", line
604:
    return _SConscript(self.fs, *files, **subst_kw)   File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scons\SCons\Script\SConscript.py", line
285:
    call_stack[-1].globals)   File "C:\Users\Darius\Downloads\iotivity-1.3.1.tar\iotivity-1.3.1\iotivity-1.3.1\build_common\android\SConscript",
line 19:
    SConscript('#/extlibs/android/ndk/SConscript')   File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scons\SCons\Script\SConscript.py", line
667:
    return method(*args, **kw)   File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scons\SCons\Script\SConscript.py", line
604:
    return _SConscript(self.fs, *files, **subst_kw)   File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scons\SCons\Script\SConscript.py", line
285:
    call_stack[-1].globals)   File "C:\Users\Darius\Downloads\iotivity-1.3.1.tar\iotivity-1.3.1\iotivity-1.3.1\extlibs\android\ndk\SConscript", line 24:
    if host_arch in ['x86_64']:
```

I did add my 7-zip folder path to `PATH` environment variable and restarted, but I still get this message. Not sure why it's even required though..

Comment: What version of Python do you have installed?  I'm going to guess it's python3.* string_escape doesn't exist in python3. Please try installing python 2.7 and scons in that.. py -2 -mpip install -U pip wheel . then py -2 -mpip install scons.   Likely you'll need to do py -3 -mpip uninstall scons.

Comment: python version 3.7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the error it looks like iotivity is using string_escape which isn't supported under python 3.*.

You'll need to install python 2.7 then:

```
py -3 -mpip uninstall scons
py -2 -mpip install -U pip setuptools wheel
py -2 -mpip install scons
```

Then try again.

Comment: I uninstalled all pyhton versions, then installed Python 2.7. When I try to install scons I get the error message `c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:150: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this.`

Comment: which version of python 2.7.x did you install? Make sure you installed the latest 2.7.x version

Comment: I updated to the latest 2.7.16. Now I get the error `Please make sure that 7-zip is in your System PATH`, even though I did and restarted. Also gives the error `NameError: name 'host_arch' is not defined:`

Comment: I changed the formatting on your log posts to be code.. otherwise it's not maintaining the lines.  The 7zip issue is iotivity. I'm just a SCons guy.. I'd say find their IRC channel or mailing list and send them this question..

Comment: You may want to mark this question answered and open a new one for 7zip..