# Python LookupError: unknown encoding: cp65001

Tags: python, mingw, mingw-w64, msys2

This question already has an answer here:

[Python 2.7 : LookupError: unknown encoding: cp65001](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35176270/python-2-7-lookuperror-unknown-encoding-cp65001)

but my case is slightly different. I'm using msys (mingw64) terminal to build a project; I have two versions of python 3.8 and 2.7. After setting:

```
set PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8
```

as suggested in the accepted answer, only python3 sees the variable:

```
  MINGW64 /c/Disk_D_Backup/Projects/zyn-fusion-build
$ set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8

  MINGW64 /c/Disk_D_Backup/Projects/zyn-fusion-build
$ python3 -c "import sys; print('Encoding='+sys.stdin.encoding)"
Encoding=utf-8

  MINGW64 /c/Disk_D_Backup/Projects/zyn-fusion-build
$ python2 -c "import sys; print('Encoding='+sys.stdin.encoding)"
Encoding=cp65001
```

Python2 doesn't. Why?

Comment: What's your python2 version?

Comment: @SuperStormer 2.7.9