# Error in anaconda when activate env

Tags: python, anaconda, environment

I installed anaconda for python 3.6, and I used "**conda create -n py27 python=2.7 anaconda**" command to install python 2.7 environment. When it finished, I typed this command "activate py27". There was error massage like in this following occured.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGGd7.jpg)

Comment: This is the error msg "Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams
LookupError: unknown encoding: 874".

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/q/878972/1005215 then https://superuser.com/q/237081/163735 and then finally https://superuser.com/q/269818/163735

Comment: I found the solution. Following this step

Comment: I found the solution. Following this step.... Go to >> Control Panel>Clock, Language and Region> click Region> Administrative >In Language for non unicode program click "Change system local" to "English(UK)"