# Conda env fails to be created

Tags: python, virtualenv, conda

I tried to setup a Python2 env with conda but get a debug message in its creation and a error report if trying to activate it.

I've already tried to reinstall Minicoda multiple times and started the CMD with admin rights. However, conda continues to make problems on my new pc - despite its newly setup and except for Python and Cuda quite empty.
(The issues with conda had been already present before I've installed Cuda.)

**Creation**

```
conda create -n python2 python=2.7 anaconda
Collecting package metadata: done
Solving environment: done


==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 4.6.8
  latest version: 4.6.11

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda



## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\python2

  added / updated specs:
    - anaconda
    - python=2.7


The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  alabaster          pkgs/main/win-64::alabaster-0.7.12-py27_0
  anaconda           pkgs/main/win-64::anaconda-2019.03-py27_0
  anaconda-client    pkgs/main/win-64::anaconda-client-1.7.2-py27_0
  anaconda-project   pkgs/main/win-64::anaconda-project-0.8.2-py27_0
  asn1crypto         pkgs/main/win-64::asn1crypto-0.24.0-py27_0
  astroid            pkgs/main/win-64::astroid-1.6.5-py27_0
  astropy            pkgs/main/win-64::astropy-2.0.9-py27hc997a72_0
  atomicwrites       pkgs/main/win-64::atomicwrites-1.3.0-py27_1
  attrs              pkgs/main/win-64::attrs-19.1.0-py27_1
  babel              pkgs/main/win-64::babel-2.6.0-py27_0
  backports          pkgs/main/win-64::backports-1.0-py27_1
  backports.functoo~ pkgs/main/win-64::backports.functools_lru_cache-1.5-py27_1
  backports.os       pkgs/main/win-64::backports.os-0.1.1-py27_0
  backports.shutil_~ pkgs/main/win-64::backports.shutil_get_terminal_size-1.0.0-py27_2
  backports.shutil_~ pkgs/main/win-64::backports.shutil_which-3.5.2-py27_0
  backports_abc      pkgs/main/win-64::backports_abc-0.5-py27h0ec6b72_0
  beautifulsoup4     pkgs/main/win-64::beautifulsoup4-4.7.1-py27_1
  bitarray           pkgs/main/win-64::bitarray-0.8.3-py27h0c8e037_0
  bkcharts           pkgs/main/win-64::bkcharts-0.2-py27h92b6de3_0
  blas               pkgs/main/win-64::blas-1.0-mkl
  bleach             pkgs/main/win-64::bleach-3.1.0-py27_0
  blosc              pkgs/main/win-64::blosc-1.15.0-hc65f11a_0
  bokeh              pkgs/main/win-64::bokeh-1.0.4-py27_0
  boto               pkgs/main/win-64::boto-2.49.0-py27_0
  bottleneck         pkgs/main/win-64::bottleneck-1.2.1-py27hc997a72_1
  bzip2              pkgs/main/win-64::bzip2-1.0.6-h0c8e037_5
  ca-certificates    pkgs/main/win-64::ca-certificates-2019.1.23-0
  cdecimal           pkgs/main/win-64::cdecimal-2.3-py27h0c8e037_3
  certifi            pkgs/main/win-64::certifi-2019.3.9-py27_0
  cffi               pkgs/main/win-64::cffi-1.12.2-py27hcfb25f9_1
  chardet            pkgs/main/win-64::chardet-3.0.4-py27_1
  click              pkgs/main/win-64::click-7.0-py27_0
  cloudpickle        pkgs/main/win-64::cloudpickle-0.8.0-py27_0
  clyent             pkgs/main/win-64::clyent-1.2.2-py27_1
  colorama           pkgs/main/win-64::colorama-0.4.1-py27_0
  comtypes           pkgs/main/win-64::comtypes-1.1.7-py27_0
  configparser       pkgs/main/win-64::configparser-3.7.3-py27_1
  console_shortcut   pkgs/main/win-64::console_shortcut-0.1.1-3
  contextlib2        pkgs/main/win-64::contextlib2-0.5.5-py27h42efda5_0
  cryptography       pkgs/main/win-64::cryptography-2.4.2-py27hc64555f_0
  curl               pkgs/main/win-64::curl-7.64.0-h7a46e7a_2
  cycler             pkgs/main/win-64::cycler-0.10.0-py27h59acbbf_0
  cython             pkgs/main/win-64::cython-0.29.6-py27hc56fc5f_0
  cytoolz            pkgs/main/win-64::cytoolz-0.9.0.1-py27h0c8e037_1
  dask               pkgs/main/win-64::dask-1.1.4-py27_1
  dask-core          pkgs/main/win-64::dask-core-1.1.4-py27_1
  decorator          pkgs/main/win-64::decorator-4.4.0-py27_1
  defusedxml         pkgs/main/win-64::defusedxml-0.5.0-py27_1
  distributed        pkgs/main/win-64::distributed-1.26.0-py27_1
  docutils           pkgs/main/win-64::docutils-0.14-py27h8652d09_0
  entrypoints        pkgs/main/win-64::entrypoints-0.3-py27_0
  enum34             pkgs/main/win-64::enum34-1.1.6-py27_1
  et_xmlfile         pkgs/main/win-64::et_xmlfile-1.0.1-py27h1de5d23_0
  fastcache          pkgs/main/win-64::fastcache-1.0.2-py27h0c8e037_2
  filelock           pkgs/main/win-64::filelock-3.0.10-py27_0
  flask              pkgs/main/win-64::flask-1.0.2-py27_1
  freetype           pkgs/main/win-64::freetype-2.9.1-h4d385ea_1
  funcsigs           pkgs/main/win-64::funcsigs-1.0.2-py27h8885ae1_0
  functools32        pkgs/main/win-64::functools32-3.2.3.2-py27_1
  future             pkgs/main/win-64::future-0.17.1-py27_0
  futures            pkgs/main/win-64::futures-3.2.0-py27_0
  get_terminal_size  pkgs/main/win-64::get_terminal_size-1.0.0-h38e98db_0
  gevent             pkgs/main/win-64::gevent-1.4.0-py27h0c8e037_0
  glob2              pkgs/main/win-64::glob2-0.6-py27_1
  greenlet           pkgs/main/win-64::greenlet-0.4.15-py27h0c8e037_0
  grin               pkgs/main/win-64::grin-1.2.1-py27_4
  h5py               pkgs/main/win-64::h5py-2.9.0-py27hb721d18_0
  hdf5               pkgs/main/win-64::hdf5-1.10.4-h530792d_0
  heapdict           pkgs/main/win-64::heapdict-1.0.0-py27_2
  html5lib           pkgs/main/win-64::html5lib-1.0.1-py27_0
  icc_rt             pkgs/main/win-64::icc_rt-2019.0.0-h0cc432a_1
  icu                pkgs/main/win-64::icu-58.2-h2aa20d9_1
  idna               pkgs/main/win-64::idna-2.8-py27_0
  imageio            pkgs/main/win-64::imageio-2.5.0-py27_0
  imagesize          pkgs/main/win-64::imagesize-1.1.0-py27_0
  importlib_metadata pkgs/main/win-64::importlib_metadata-0.8-py27_0
  intel-openmp       pkgs/main/win-64::intel-openmp-2019.3-203
  ipaddress          pkgs/main/win-64::ipaddress-1.0.22-py27_0
  ipykernel          pkgs/main/win-64::ipykernel-4.10.0-py27_0
  ipython            pkgs/main/win-64::ipython-5.8.0-py27_0
  ipython_genutils   pkgs/main/win-64::ipython_genutils-0.2.0-py27hbe997df_0
  ipywidgets         pkgs/main/win-64::ipywidgets-7.4.2-py27_0
  isort              pkgs/main/win-64::isort-4.3.16-py27_0
  itsdangerous       pkgs/main/win-64::itsdangerous-1.1.0-py27_0
  jdcal              pkgs/main/win-64::jdcal-1.4-py27_0
  jedi               pkgs/main/win-64::jedi-0.13.3-py27_0
  jinja2             pkgs/main/win-64::jinja2-2.10-py27_0
  jpeg               pkgs/main/win-64::jpeg-9b-ha175dff_2
  jsonschema         pkgs/main/win-64::jsonschema-3.0.1-py27_0
  jupyter            pkgs/main/win-64::jupyter-1.0.0-py27_7
  jupyter_client     pkgs/main/win-64::jupyter_client-5.2.4-py27_0
  jupyter_console    pkgs/main/win-64::jupyter_console-5.2.0-py27_1
  jupyter_core       pkgs/main/win-64::jupyter_core-4.4.0-py27_0
  jupyterlab         pkgs/main/win-64::jupyterlab-0.33.11-py27_0
  jupyterlab_launch~ pkgs/main/win-64::jupyterlab_launcher-0.11.2-py27h28b3542_0
  keyring            pkgs/main/win-64::keyring-18.0.0-py27_0
  kiwisolver         pkgs/main/win-64::kiwisolver-1.0.1-py27hc56fc5f_0
  krb5               pkgs/main/win-64::krb5-1.16.1-hb4d044e_6
  lazy-object-proxy  pkgs/main/win-64::lazy-object-proxy-1.3.1-py27h0c8e037_2
  libarchive         pkgs/main/win-64::libarchive-3.3.3-h96cdc4e_0
  libcurl            pkgs/main/win-64::libcurl-7.64.0-h7a46e7a_2
  libiconv           pkgs/main/win-64::libiconv-1.15-hda2e4ec_7
  libpng             pkgs/main/win-64::libpng-1.6.36-h7a46e7a_0
  libsodium          pkgs/main/win-64::libsodium-1.0.16-h8b3e59e_0
  libssh2            pkgs/main/win-64::libssh2-1.8.0-h77a7533_4
  libtiff            pkgs/main/win-64::libtiff-4.0.10-h1c3b264_2
  libxml2            pkgs/main/win-64::libxml2-2.9.9-h325896a_0
  libxslt            pkgs/main/win-64::libxslt-1.1.33-h803002f_0
  linecache2         pkgs/main/win-64::linecache2-1.0.0-py27_0
  llvmlite           pkgs/main/win-64::llvmlite-0.28.0-py27hc56fc5f_0
  locket             pkgs/main/win-64::locket-0.2.0-py27h1ca288a_1
  lxml               pkgs/main/win-64::lxml-4.3.2-py27h31b8cb8_0
  lz4-c              pkgs/main/win-64::lz4-c-1.8.1.2-h3cc03e0_0
  lzo                pkgs/main/win-64::lzo-2.10-h0bb7fe3_2
  m2w64-gcc-libgfor~ pkgs/msys2/win-64::m2w64-gcc-libgfortran-5.3.0-6
  m2w64-gcc-libs     pkgs/msys2/win-64::m2w64-gcc-libs-5.3.0-7
  m2w64-gcc-libs-co~ pkgs/msys2/win-64::m2w64-gcc-libs-core-5.3.0-7
  m2w64-gmp          pkgs/msys2/win-64::m2w64-gmp-6.1.0-2
  m2w64-libwinpthre~ pkgs/msys2/win-64::m2w64-libwinpthread-git-5.0.0.4634.697f757-2
  markupsafe         pkgs/main/win-64::markupsafe-1.1.1-py27h0c8e037_0
  matplotlib         pkgs/main/win-64::matplotlib-2.2.3-py27h263d877_0
  mccabe             pkgs/main/win-64::mccabe-0.6.1-py27_1
  menuinst           pkgs/main/win-64::menuinst-1.4.16-py27h0c8e037_0
  mistune            pkgs/main/win-64::mistune-0.8.4-py27h0c8e037_0
  mkl                pkgs/main/win-64::mkl-2019.3-203
  mkl-service        pkgs/main/win-64::mkl-service-1.1.2-py27h0b88c2a_5
  mkl_fft            pkgs/main/win-64::mkl_fft-1.0.10-py27h44c1dab_0
  more-itertools     pkgs/main/win-64::more-itertools-5.0.0-py27_0
  mpmath             pkgs/main/win-64::mpmath-1.1.0-py27_0
  msgpack-python     pkgs/main/win-64::msgpack-python-0.6.1-py27hdc96acc_1
  msys2-conda-epoch  pkgs/msys2/win-64::msys2-conda-epoch-20160418-1
  multipledispatch   pkgs/main/win-64::multipledispatch-0.6.0-py27_0
  nbconvert          pkgs/main/win-64::nbconvert-5.4.1-py27_3
  nbformat           pkgs/main/win-64::nbformat-4.4.0-py27hf49b375_0
  networkx           pkgs/main/win-64::networkx-2.2-py27_1
  nltk               pkgs/main/win-64::nltk-3.4-py27_1
  nose               pkgs/main/win-64::nose-1.3.7-py27_2
  notebook           pkgs/main/win-64::notebook-5.7.8-py27_0
  numba              pkgs/main/win-64::numba-0.43.1-py27h39f3610_0
  numexpr            pkgs/main/win-64::numexpr-2.6.9-py27haac76bc_0
  numpy              pkgs/main/win-64::numpy-1.16.2-py27h5fc8d92_0
  numpy-base         pkgs/main/win-64::numpy-base-1.16.2-py27hb1d0314_0
  numpydoc           pkgs/main/win-64::numpydoc-0.8.0-py27_0
  olefile            pkgs/main/win-64::olefile-0.46-py27_0
  openpyxl           pkgs/main/win-64::openpyxl-2.6.1-py27_1
  openssl            pkgs/main/win-64::openssl-1.0.2r-h0c8e037_0
  packaging          pkgs/main/win-64::packaging-19.0-py27_0
  pandas             pkgs/main/win-64::pandas-0.24.2-py27hc56fc5f_0
  pandoc             pkgs/main/win-64::pandoc-2.2.3.2-0
  pandocfilters      pkgs/main/win-64::pandocfilters-1.4.2-py27_1
  parso              pkgs/main/win-64::parso-0.3.4-py27_0
  partd              pkgs/main/win-64::partd-0.3.10-py27_1
  path.py            pkgs/main/win-64::path.py-11.5.0-py27_0
  pathlib2           pkgs/main/win-64::pathlib2-2.3.3-py27_0
  patsy              pkgs/main/win-64::patsy-0.5.1-py27_0
  pep8               pkgs/main/win-64::pep8-1.7.1-py27_0
  pickleshare        pkgs/main/win-64::pickleshare-0.7.5-py27_0
  pillow             pkgs/main/win-64::pillow-5.4.1-py27h5b88493_0
  pip                pkgs/main/win-64::pip-19.0.3-py27_0
  pkginfo            pkgs/main/win-64::pkginfo-1.5.0.1-py27_0
  pluggy             pkgs/main/win-64::pluggy-0.9.0-py27_0
  ply                pkgs/main/win-64::ply-3.11-py27_0
  powershell_shortc~ pkgs/main/win-64::powershell_shortcut-0.0.1-2
  prometheus_client  pkgs/main/win-64::prometheus_client-0.6.0-py27_0
  prompt_toolkit     pkgs/main/win-64::prompt_toolkit-1.0.15-py27h3a8ec6a_0
  psutil             pkgs/main/win-64::psutil-5.5.0-py27h0c8e037_0
  py                 pkgs/main/win-64::py-1.8.0-py27_0
  pycodestyle        pkgs/main/win-64::pycodestyle-2.5.0-py27_0
  pycosat            pkgs/main/win-64::pycosat-0.6.3-py27h0c8e037_0
  pycparser          pkgs/main/win-64::pycparser-2.19-py27_0
  pycrypto           pkgs/main/win-64::pycrypto-2.6.1-py27h0c8e037_9
  pycurl             pkgs/main/win-64::pycurl-7.43.0.2-py27hc64555f_0
  pyflakes           pkgs/main/win-64::pyflakes-2.1.1-py27_0
  pygments           pkgs/main/win-64::pygments-2.3.1-py27_0
  pylint             pkgs/main/win-64::pylint-1.9.2-py27_0
  pyodbc             pkgs/main/win-64::pyodbc-4.0.26-py27hc56fc5f_0
  pyopenssl          pkgs/main/win-64::pyopenssl-19.0.0-py27_0
  pyparsing          pkgs/main/win-64::pyparsing-2.3.1-py27_0
  pyqt               pkgs/main/win-64::pyqt-5.6.0-py27h6e61f57_6
  pyreadline         pkgs/main/win-64::pyreadline-2.1-py27_1
  pyrsistent         pkgs/main/win-64::pyrsistent-0.14.11-py27h0c8e037_0
  pysocks            pkgs/main/win-64::pysocks-1.6.8-py27_0
  pytables           pkgs/main/win-64::pytables-3.5.1-py27h6a9b274_0
  pytest             pkgs/main/win-64::pytest-4.3.1-py27_0
  python             pkgs/main/win-64::python-2.7.16-hcb6e200_0
  python-dateutil    pkgs/main/win-64::python-dateutil-2.8.0-py27_0
  python-libarchive~ pkgs/main/win-64::python-libarchive-c-2.8-py27_6
  pytz               pkgs/main/win-64::pytz-2018.9-py27_0
  pywavelets         pkgs/main/win-64::pywavelets-1.0.2-py27hc997a72_0
  pywin32            pkgs/main/win-64::pywin32-223-py27h0c8e037_1
  pywinpty           pkgs/main/win-64::pywinpty-0.5.5-py27_1000
  pyyaml             pkgs/main/win-64::pyyaml-5.1-py27h0c8e037_0
  pyzmq              pkgs/main/win-64::pyzmq-18.0.0-py27hc56fc5f_0
  qt                 pkgs/main/win-64::qt-5.6.2-vc9hc26998b_12
  qtawesome          pkgs/main/win-64::qtawesome-0.5.7-py27_1
  qtconsole          pkgs/main/win-64::qtconsole-4.4.3-py27_0
  qtpy               pkgs/main/win-64::qtpy-1.7.0-py27_1
  requests           pkgs/main/win-64::requests-2.21.0-py27_0
  rope               pkgs/main/win-64::rope-0.12.0-py27_0
  ruamel_yaml        pkgs/main/win-64::ruamel_yaml-0.15.46-py27h0c8e037_0
  scandir            pkgs/main/win-64::scandir-1.10.0-py27h0c8e037_0
  scikit-image       pkgs/main/win-64::scikit-image-0.14.2-py27hc56fc5f_0
  scikit-learn       pkgs/main/win-64::scikit-learn-0.20.3-py27hf381715_0
  scipy              pkgs/main/win-64::scipy-1.2.1-py27h4c3ab11_0
  seaborn            pkgs/main/win-64::seaborn-0.9.0-py27_0
  send2trash         pkgs/main/win-64::send2trash-1.5.0-py27_0
  setuptools         pkgs/main/win-64::setuptools-40.8.0-py27_0
  simplegeneric      pkgs/main/win-64::simplegeneric-0.8.1-py27_2
  singledispatch     pkgs/main/win-64::singledispatch-3.4.0.3-py27h3f9d112_0
  sip                pkgs/main/win-64::sip-4.18.1-py27hc56fc5f_2
  six                pkgs/main/win-64::six-1.12.0-py27_0
  snappy             pkgs/main/win-64::snappy-1.1.7-he46498f_3
  snowballstemmer    pkgs/main/win-64::snowballstemmer-1.2.1-py27h28d3bf7_0
  sortedcollections  pkgs/main/win-64::sortedcollections-1.1.2-py27_0
  sortedcontainers   pkgs/main/win-64::sortedcontainers-2.1.0-py27_0
  soupsieve          pkgs/main/win-64::soupsieve-1.8-py27_0
  sphinx             pkgs/main/win-64::sphinx-1.8.5-py27_0
  sphinxcontrib      pkgs/main/win-64::sphinxcontrib-1.0-py27_1
  sphinxcontrib-web~ pkgs/main/win-64::sphinxcontrib-websupport-1.1.0-py27_1
  spyder             pkgs/main/win-64::spyder-3.3.3-py27_0
  spyder-kernels     pkgs/main/win-64::spyder-kernels-0.4.2-py27_0
  sqlalchemy         pkgs/main/win-64::sqlalchemy-1.3.1-py27h0c8e037_0
  sqlite             pkgs/main/win-64::sqlite-3.27.2-h0c8e037_0
  ssl_match_hostname pkgs/main/win-64::ssl_match_hostname-3.7.0.1-py27_0
  statsmodels        pkgs/main/win-64::statsmodels-0.9.0-py27hc997a72_0
  subprocess32       pkgs/main/win-64::subprocess32-3.5.3-py27h0c8e037_0
  sympy              pkgs/main/win-64::sympy-1.3-py27_0
  tblib              pkgs/main/win-64::tblib-1.3.2-py27h8ae915c_0
  terminado          pkgs/main/win-64::terminado-0.8.1-py27_1
  testpath           pkgs/main/win-64::testpath-0.4.2-py27_0
  tk                 pkgs/main/win-64::tk-8.6.8-h0c8e037_0
  toolz              pkgs/main/win-64::toolz-0.9.0-py27_0
  tornado            pkgs/main/win-64::tornado-5.1.1-py27h0c8e037_0
  tqdm               pkgs/main/win-64::tqdm-4.31.1-py27_1
  traceback2         pkgs/main/win-64::traceback2-1.4.0-py27_0
  traitlets          pkgs/main/win-64::traitlets-4.3.2-py27h1b1b3a5_0
  typing             pkgs/main/win-64::typing-3.6.6-py27_0
  unicodecsv         pkgs/main/win-64::unicodecsv-0.14.1-py27h0bf7bb0_0
  unittest2          pkgs/main/win-64::unittest2-1.1.0-py27_0
  urllib3            pkgs/main/win-64::urllib3-1.24.1-py27_0
  vc                 pkgs/main/win-64::vc-9-h7299396_1
  vs2008_runtime     pkgs/main/win-64::vs2008_runtime-9.00.30729.1-hfaea7d5_1
  vs2015_runtime     pkgs/main/win-64::vs2015_runtime-14.15.26706-h3a45250_0
  wcwidth            pkgs/main/win-64::wcwidth-0.1.7-py27hb1a0d82_0
  webencodings       pkgs/main/win-64::webencodings-0.5.1-py27_1
  werkzeug           pkgs/main/win-64::werkzeug-0.14.1-py27_0
  wheel              pkgs/main/win-64::wheel-0.33.1-py27_0
  widgetsnbextension pkgs/main/win-64::widgetsnbextension-3.4.2-py27_0
  win_inet_pton      pkgs/main/win-64::win_inet_pton-1.1.0-py27_0
  win_unicode_conso~ pkgs/main/win-64::win_unicode_console-0.5-py27hc037021_0
  wincertstore       pkgs/main/win-64::wincertstore-0.2-py27hf04cefb_0
  winpty             pkgs/main/win-64::winpty-0.4.3-4
  wrapt              pkgs/main/win-64::wrapt-1.11.1-py27h0c8e037_0
  xlrd               pkgs/main/win-64::xlrd-1.2.0-py27_0
  xlsxwriter         pkgs/main/win-64::xlsxwriter-1.1.5-py27_0
  xlwings            pkgs/main/win-64::xlwings-0.15.4-py27_0
  xlwt               pkgs/main/win-64::xlwt-1.3.0-py27h2271735_0
  xz                 pkgs/main/win-64::xz-5.2.4-h3cc03e0_4
  yaml               pkgs/main/win-64::yaml-0.1.7-h3e6d941_2
  zeromq             pkgs/main/win-64::zeromq-4.3.1-h2880e7c_3
  zict               pkgs/main/win-64::zict-0.1.4-py27_0
  zipp               pkgs/main/win-64::zipp-0.3.3-py27_1
  zlib               pkgs/main/win-64::zlib-1.2.11-h3cc03e0_3
  zstd               pkgs/main/win-64::zstd-1.3.7-h1b0e4d7_0


Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: | DEBUG menuinst_win32:__init__(196): Menu: name: 'Anaconda${PY_VER} ${PLATFORM}', prefix: 'C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\python2', env_name: 'python2', mode: 'system', used_mode: 'system'
DEBUG menuinst_win32:create(320): Shortcut cmd is %windir%\System32\cmd.exe, args are ['"/K"', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\Scripts\\activate.bat', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\envs\\python2']
| DEBUG menuinst_win32:__init__(196): Menu: name: 'Anaconda${PY_VER} ${PLATFORM}', prefix: 'C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\python2', env_name: 'python2', mode: 'system', used_mode: 'system'
DEBUG menuinst_win32:create(320): Shortcut cmd is %windir%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe, args are ['-ExecutionPolicy', 'ByPass', '-NoExit', '-Command', '"& \'C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\shell\\condabin\\conda-hook.ps1\' ; conda activate \'C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\envs\\python2\' "']
| DEBUG menuinst_win32:__init__(196): Menu: name: 'Anaconda${PY_VER} ${PLATFORM}', prefix: 'C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\python2', env_name: 'python2', mode: 'system', used_mode: 'system'
DEBUG menuinst_win32:create(320): Shortcut cmd is C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\python.exe, args are ['C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\cwp.py', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\envs\\python2', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\envs\\python2\\python.exe', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\envs\\python2\\Scripts\\jupyter-notebook-script.py', '"%USERPROFILE%/"']
\ DEBUG menuinst_win32:__init__(196): Menu: name: 'Anaconda${PY_VER} ${PLATFORM}', prefix: 'C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\python2', env_name: 'python2', mode: 'system', used_mode: 'system'
DEBUG menuinst_win32:create(320): Shortcut cmd is C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\pythonw.exe, args are ['C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\cwp.py', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\envs\\python2', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\envs\\python2\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\envs\\python2\\Scripts\\spyder-script.py']
DEBUG menuinst_win32:create(320): Shortcut cmd is C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\python.exe, args are ['C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\cwp.py', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\envs\\python2', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\envs\\python2\\python.exe', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\envs\\python2\\Scripts\\spyder-script.py', '--reset']
done
#
# To activate this environment, use:
# > activate python2
#
# To deactivate an active environment, use:
# > deactivate
#
# * for power-users using bash, you must source
#
```

**Activation**

```
activate python2

# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 105, in main
        return activator_main()
      File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\activate.py", line 838, in main
        print(activator.execute(), end='')
      File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\activate.py", line 110, in execute
        return getattr(self, self.command)()
      File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\activate.py", line 88, in activate
        return self._finalize(self._yield_commands(builder_result), self.tempfile_extension)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\activate.py", line 78, in _finalize
        tf.write(ensure_binary(self.command_join.join(commands)))
      File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\activate.py", line 536, in ensure_binary
        return value.encode(encoding)
    LookupError: unknown encoding: 65001

`$ C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py shell.cmd.exe activate python2`

  environment variables:
                 CIO_TEST=<not set>
                CONDA_EXE=C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\condabin\..\Scripts\conda.exe
               CONDA_ROOT=C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3
                CUDA_PATH=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.0
                 HOMEPATH=\Users\georg
          NVTOOLSEXT_PATH=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NvToolsExt\
                     PATH=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing
                          Toolkit\CUDA\v10.0\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing
                          Toolkit\CUDA\v10.0\libnvvp;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing
                          Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing
                          Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\libnvvp;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-
                          bin;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin;C:\Program Files
                          (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files
                          (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Program
                          Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Windows\sys
                          tem32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsP
                          owerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files
                          (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program
                          Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program
                          Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA
                          Corporation\NVIDIA NGX;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA
                          Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program
                          Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:
                          \ProgramData\Miniconda3;C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Scripts;C:\ProgramDa
                          ta\Miniconda3\Library\bin;C:\Users\georg\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windo
                          wsApps;C:\Users\georg\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
             PSMODULEPATH=C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\Windows
                          PowerShell\v1.0\Modules
       REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
            SSL_CERT_FILE=<not set>

     active environment : None
       user config file : C:\Users\georg\.condarc
 populated config files :
          conda version : 4.6.8
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.7.1.final.0
       base environment : C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\georg\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\georg\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\georg\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\georg\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.6.8 requests/2.21.0 CPython/3.7.1 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.17763
          administrator : True
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False


An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.

If submitted, this report will be used by core maintainers to improve
future releases of conda.
Would you like conda to send this report to the core maintainers?

y
Upload did not complete.

Thank you for helping to improve conda.
Opt-in to always sending reports (and not see this message again)
by running

    $ conda config --set report_errors true
```

**Attempts**

- set PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8
- [Change the System Encoding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50MXn.png)
- Downgrading Pyinstaller with pip install pyinstaller==3.1
- Running from Windows Git Bash Running from Anaconda CMD Tool

What is wrong here?
Thank you in anticipation! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal Python error: Py\_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams LookupError: unknown encoding: 65001](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51053464/fatal-python-error-py-initialize-cant-initialize-sys-standard-streams-lookupe)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+LookupError%3A+unknown+encoding%3A+65001

Comment: The solutions provided under both links did not work. See above. They actually made it worse, since now I even get the error message for removing conda envs.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

The solution is to set the coding page in the Windows setting, the env variable and in CMD to 65001, i.e. UTF-8.
From all previous solution the last step in CMD was missing.

**Steps**

1. run "set PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8" in CMD (put this into system env to make it permanent)
2. [Change the System Encoding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50MXn.png)
3. (optional) Downgrading Pyinstaller with "pip install pyinstaller==3.1" (might be a bug source)
4. in cmd run "chcp 65001" before creating the conda env