# Problems when Installing Noetic in Raspberry pi with Docker

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, docker, ros

Background: I have been able to build and run ROS kinetic and ROS2 eloquent containers in my Raspberry Pi4 in the past.

I am trying to build and run ROS noetic. However I am getting an error.
To show this I do the most simple things

```
docker pull ros:noetic
```

then I do

```
docker image ls
```

and I can see that the image is there

but when I do

```
docker run -it ros:noetic
```

I get

```
Fatal Python error: pyinit_main: can't initialize time
Python runtime state: core initialized
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted

Current thread 0xb6ff1460 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
```

I wonder what is happening and how to solve this

My suspicion is that since noetic is using Python 3 and not 2, something is failing due to versions

Comments: I know that ROS kinetic uses python 2 but I assumed ROS2 eloquent used Python 3! Now I found that it uses python 2 too!

## MORE Information:

I have been able to build and run ROS noetic containers in my Ubuntu desktop machine.
So I imagine it is a raspberry pi problem. However it seems that it is possible to install noetic natively on RPi, so I wonder if it is a problem with the Noetic Docker image...

Answer (score 7):

I had the exact same issue and the following workaround worked:

```
docker run --privileged
```

[Docker documentation on --privileged switch](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#full-container-capabilities---privileged)

Comment: this removes any notion of security from running in a container. Use the answer above about upgrading libseccomp2

Answer (score 3):

Next commands on host machine, helped me out:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 04EE7237B7D453EC 648ACFD622F3D138
echo "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/buster-backports.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -t buster-backports libseccomp2
```

Comment: This did the trick for me as well. But could you please write 2-3 lines what this exactly does and why it fixes the permissions :) ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a docker issue, since it works if you do that in another machine. It's an issue related to how it get time.

Maybe it can helps you:

[Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams LookupError: unknown encoding: 65001](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51053464/fatal-python-error-py-initialize-cant-initialize-sys-standard-streams-lookupe)

Answer (score 0):

After a bunch of googling, and trying different solutions, I installed a 64-bit version of ubuntu onto my rpi4, and it worked perfectly after that.
The rpi installer is a quick and easy way to flash the new os:
https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/