# Fix "Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams"

Tags: python, subprocess, dm-script

I have **two python environments** with different versions **running in parallel.** When I execute a python script (`test2.py`) from one python environment in the other python environment, I get the following error:

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\GMS_VENV_PYTHON\lib\io.py", line 52, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\GMS_VENV_PYTHON\lib\abc.py", line 147
    print(f"Class: {cls.__module__}.{cls.__qualname__}", file=file)
                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So my setup is this:

```
Python 3.7
 (test.py)
    │
    │                           Python 3.5.6
    ├───────────────────────────────┐
    ┆                               │
    ┆                         execute test2.py
    ┆                               │
    ┆                            Error
```

How can I fix this?

*For [dm-script](/questions/tagged/dm-script)-people*: How can I execute a module with a different python version in Digital Micrograph?

---

### Details

I have two python files.

File 1 (`test.py`):

```py
# execute in Digital Micrograph
import os
import subprocess

command = ['C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\envs\\legacy\\python.exe', 
           os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'test2.py')]
print(*command)

result = subprocess.run(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
print("Subprocess result: '{}', '{}'".format(result.stdout.decode("utf-8"), result.stderr.decode("utf-8")))
```

and File 2 (`test2.py`)

```py
# only executable in python 3.5.6
print("Hi")
```

in the same directory. `test.py` is executing `test2.py` with a different python version (python 3.5.6, `legacy` environment).

My python script (`test.py`) is running in the python interpreter in a third party program ([Digital Micrograph](https://www.gatan.com/products/tem-analysis/gatan-microscopy-suite-software)). This program installs a miniconda python enviromnent called `GMS_VENV_PYTHON` (python version 3.7.x) which can be seen in the above traceback. The `legacy` miniconda environment is used only for running `test2.py` (from `test.py`) in python version 3.5.6.

When I run `test.py` from the command line (also in the conda `GMS_VENV_PYTHON` environment), I get the expected output from `test2.py` in `test.py`. When I run the exact same file in Digital Micrograph, I get the response

```
Subprocess result: '', 'Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\GMS_VENV_PYTHON\lib\io.py", line 52, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\GMS_VENV_PYTHON\lib\abc.py", line 147
    print(f"Class: {cls.__module__}.{cls.__qualname__}", file=file)
                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
'
```

This tells me the following (I guess):

- The `test2.py` is called since this is the error output of the subprocess call. So the `subprocess.run()` function seems to work fine
- The paths are in the `GMS_VENV_PYTHON` environment which is *wrong in this case*. Since this is `test2.py`, they should be in the `legacy` paths
- There is a `SyntaxError` because a [f-string (Literal String Interpolation)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) is used which is introduced with python 3.6. So the executing python version is before 3.6. So the `legacy` python environment is used.
- `test2.py` uses either use `io` nor `abc` (I don't know what to conclude here; are those modules loaded by default when executing python?)

So I guess this means, that the standard modules are loaded (I don't know why, probably because they are always loaded) from the wrong destination.

How can I fix this? (See *What I've tried > PATH* for more details)

---

### What I've tried so far

#### Encoding

I came across this post "[Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams LookupError: unknown encoding: 65001](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51053464/5934316)" telling me, that there might be problems with the encoding. I know that Digital Micrograph internally uses ISO 8859-1. I tried to use `python -X utf8` and `python -X utf8` (`test2.py` doesn't care about UTF-8, it is ASCII only) as shown below. But neither of them worked

```py
command = ['C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\envs\\legacy\\python.exe', 
           "-X", "utf8=0", 
           os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'test2.py')]
```

#### PATH

As far as I can tell, I think this is the problem. The answer "https://stackoverflow.com/a/31877629/5934316" of the post "[PyCharm: Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26569828/5934316)" suggests to change the `PYTHONPATH`.

So to specify my question:

1. Is this the way to go?
2. How can I set the `PYTHONPATH` for only the subprocess (while executing python with other libraries in the main thread)?
3. Is there a better way to have two different python versions at the same time?

Thank you for your help.

---

### Background

I am currently writing a program for handling an electron microscope. I need the "environment" (the graphical interface, the help tools but also hardware access) from Digital Micrograph. So there is no way around using it. And DigitalMicrograph does only support python 3.7.

On the other hand I need an external module which is only available for python 3.5.6. Also there is no way around using this module since it controlls other hardware.

Both rely on python C modules. Since they are compiled already, there is no possibility to check if they work with other versions. Also they are controlling highly sensitive aperatures where one does not want to change code. So in short words: I need two python versions parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was actually quite close. The problem is, that **python imports invalid modules from a wrong location**. In my case modules were imported from another python installation due to a wrong path. Modifying the `PYTHONPATH` according to "https://stackoverflow.com/a/4453495/5934316" works for my example.

```py
import os

my_env = os.environ.copy()
my_env["PYTHONHOME"] = "C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\envs\\legacy"
my_env["PYTHONPATH"] = "C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\envs\\legacy;"
my_env["PATH"] = my_env["PATH"].replace("C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\envs\\GMS_VENV_PYTHON", 
                                        "C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\envs\\legacy")

command = ["C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\envs\\legacy\\python.exe", 
           os.path.join(path, "test2.py")]

result = subprocess.run(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, env=my_env)
```

---

For Digital Micrograph users: The python environment is saved in the global tags in "Private:Python:Python Path". So replace:

```py
import DigitalMicrograph as DM

# ...

success, gms_venv = DM.GetPersistentTagGroup().GetTagAsString("Private:Python:Python Path")

if not success:
    raise KeyError("Python path is not set.")

my_env["PATH"] = my_env["PATH"].replace(gms_venv, "C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\envs\\legacy")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had set "PYTHONPATH" as "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3" for my python (base) python environment before, but i found when I had changed to another env my python still import basic python package from "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3",which means it get the wrong basic package with the wrong "System environment variables" config.

so I delete "PYTHONPATH" from my windows "System environment variables", and that will be fixed.